# VB6 app icon in Windows 7 taskbar is blurred

Tags: vb6, windows-7-x64, taskbar

I have a VB6 application and one of the Form icon is set as application icon. The problem is that in Windows 7 the icon looks blurred even though the icon contains 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48 sizes.

Is there a way around this problem? It tried the SendMessage(... SETICON... ICON_BIG) but it does not seems to work.

Comment: Which `hWnd` did you try to `SendMessage` to? Try to send it to `GetParent(Form1.hWnd)` which is the hidden single owner of every VB6 "ownerless" form that holds the icon in Applications tab in Task Manager.

Comment: Where does the icon appear blurred? On the Form or when looking at the exe in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Matt The title says it's in the Windows 7 taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

What colour depth are the icons in your ico file?

VB6 (I believe) supports a maximum 8 bit colour depth (256 colours) for icons:-

So if there is no size 48 x 48 icon in 8 bit colour depth it could be using the nearest match and scaling it to 48 x 48

EDIT:

I just tried this using an icon that did not have a 48 x 48 icon at 8 bit depth (but did have 48 x 48 at higher depths) and the icon used in the taskbar was the 32bit icon at 8 bit colour depth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to understand the full heuristics used to choose the icon image to display in various places, but I think what is happening here is that your 48x48 image is being taken and scaled down.

I suspect what happens with a VB6 program on many versions of Windows is that if there is no 16-color 16x16 image then a larger size gets taken and scaled.  The reason may simply be due to the order of the images in the ICO resource/file.

If you edit your ICO and add a 16-color version of your 16x16 image your "problem" may disappear.