# Why does the icon for my project look so horrible in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I have an old VB6 project that I updated for Windows 7, including icons with 48x48 size.  When I run it, the icon in the task bar appears washed out.

[image]

I think I have all the necessary icon sizes in the .ico file, but maybe I am missing something:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might try these suggestions and if you find a definitive answer, post it for us. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309875/vb6-app-icon-in-windows-7-taskbar-is-blurred

Comment: @Beaner I implemented the solution in my answer and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

VB6 only supports 16 color icons which will cause dithering and, consequently, the transparency information is limited to a single bit indicating whether a pixel is transparent or not.

As always, you can rely on a set of Windows' APIs to overcome this limitation.
Here's a link to a forum post explaining how to use 256 color icons: [VB6 System Tray Icon Color Depth](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?640863-RESOLVED-VB6-System-Tray-Icon-Color-Depth)

Answer (score 3):

I found a [vbaccelerator article](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Setting_the_App_Icon_Correctly/article.asp) from the XP days that seems to work in Windows 7 as well.  The key is to follow the instructions to the letter.  And it only works in a compiled app, not in the IDE.  Finally, when you add a 256x256 image to your icon, make sure that it's not PNG compressed when the icon is saved (most editors have a preference for that hidden away somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:
Enable visual styles; add manifest to your application and the VB IDE.

Adding manifest to the VB IDE is a bit tricky in Vista and above. Follow instructions here:
http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/forms/vbidevista.htm

Then, to add the manifest to your application.
This will also enable you to make your application start as elevated (Have Admin access when started):
Step 1: Create your manifest text-file.
There are 2 options: The normal manifest-file, and a manifest-file for requiring Admin-privileges.

Manifest File:
(Download link at the end)

Manifest Admin File:
(Download link at the end)

Once you have created your manifest-file, add it to your project:

Open the Resource Editor, and click "Add Custom Resource..." (The button next to the question-mark).
Select your manifest-file and add it to the editor.
Now, double-click on the newly added resource, to edit it's properties.
Set these values:

Type: #24

ID: 1

Now, here is the last and most important step:

Set your project to start with Sub Main.
In Sub Main, as one of the first things, you call the function InitCommonControls.
This HAS TO BE CALLED before any Forms, Controls or other Dialogs are loaded!

InitCommonControls:
(Download link at the end)

That's it!
Your VB6 is not fully up to date and using visual styles.

Download link, as promised:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/neyueoozv87k1qd/AACbID8_aC718LCjs12T16Oqa?dl=0